# I am trying to loop over an array of strings and firing api calls to reload the collection view

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, asynchronous, alamofire

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces
import Alamofire
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listData?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CityCollectionViewCell

    let city = listData![indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
    let name = city?.object(forKey: "name") as? String
    let main = city?.object(forKey: "main") as! NSDictionary
    let temp = main.object(forKey: "temp") as? Double
    let date1 = city?.object(forKey: "dt")

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: date1 as! TimeInterval)
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" //Specify your format that you want
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    cell.cityLabel.text = name!
    cell.lastUpdatedLabel.text = strDate
    cell.tempLabel.text = "\(temp!)"

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cv.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row;
    let selectedCity = list![row];

    userDefaults?.set(selectedCity, forKey: "citySelection");
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "selectCity", sender: self);
}


@IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!

var userDefaults:UserDefaults?;

var list:NSMutableArray?
var listData:NSMutableArray?
let group = DispatchGroup()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard;

}


@IBAction func addCity(_ sender: Any) {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    let addressFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    addressFilter.type = .city
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = addressFilter
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    updateValues()

}
func updateValues()  {
    let list = getSearchHistory()
    print(list)
        let count = list.count
    if count > 0
     {
        for item in list {
            group.enter()
                getData(name: item as! String)
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            self.cv.reloadData()
        })
    }
}

func getData(name: String)  {
    let modified = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(modified)&APPID=-------"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.get).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        (response) -> Void in

        let city = response.result.value as! NSDictionary;
        self.listData?.add(city)
        print(self.listData)
        self.group.leave()
    })
}

func addToSearchHistory(locationName:String) {

    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "SavedPlaces", into: managedContext)
    entity.setValue(locationName, forKey: "name")

    do {
        try managedContext.save();
    }
    catch {
        print("Core data error");
    }
}

func getSearchHistory() -> NSMutableArray {
    let returnData = NSMutableArray()
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    do {
        let req = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SavedPlaces");

        let data = try managedContext.fetch(req) as! [NSManagedObject];

        for item in data {
            let name = item.value(forKey: "name") as? String;
            returnData.add(name!);
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Core data error");
    }

    return returnData;
}

}

 extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// Handle the user's selection.
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    self.addToSearchHistory(locationName: place.name)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// User canceled the operation.
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

 }
```

I am trying to load the values from stored data using core Data, and then looping over strings and calling the api and then adding it to a new array from which I am populating the collection view.

Problem: I am having all the values(Cities names) list populated correctly but after calling the api and call the "UpdateUI" function I am getting only one cell.
[gif file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18ORXxwkme6QYAv_v90S_BWGtlpf-jQSo)

Answer (score 0):

Requests are not yet completed this is an asynchronous task wait i will handle the code for you , this way whenever a new response come that tableView will be reloaded to reflect that

```
   func updateValues()  {
    let list = getSearchHistory()

    if !list.isEmpty
     {
        for item in list {
                getData(name: item as! String)
        }

    }
}

func getData(name: String)  {
    let modified = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let rr = NSMutableArray()
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(modified)&APPID=------------------"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.get).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        (response) -> Void in

        let city = response.result.value as! NSDictionary;

        rr.add(city)
       self.listData.append(rr)

       DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
               self.cv.reloadData()
         }           



    })
}
```

Also note a very important step in response you overwrite current array not append to it

```
  self.listData = rr
```

it should be

```
 self.listData.append(rr)
```

and that causes the permanent display of one item whether a load occurs or not

[image]

Also  don't forget to initalize **listData** in viewDidLoad

```
  listData = NSMutableArray()
```

Try to parse the api like this

```
-(void)getDataforCity:(NSString*)cityName
{

  NSURL*url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?APPID=%@&q=%@",openWeatherMapBaseURL,openWeatherMapAPIKey,cityName]];

 [NSURLSession.sharedSession dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if(error == nil)
    {

        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

       NSDictionary*main = json[@"main"];

        NSString*humidity = main[@"humidity"];

        NSString*pressure = main[@"pressure"];

        NSString*temp = main[@"temp"];

        NSString*tempMax = main[@"temp_max"];

        NSString*tempMin = main[@"temp_min"];

        NSArray*weatherArr = json[@"weather"];

        NSDictionary*weather = weatherArr[0];

        NSString*description = weather[@"description"];

        NSDictionary*wind = json[@"wind"];

        NSString*deg = wind[@"deg"];

        NSString*speed = wind[@"speed"];

        NSLog(@"humidity %@ : ",humidity);
        NSLog(@"pressure %@ : ",pressure);
        NSLog(@"temp %@ : ",temp);
        NSLog(@"tempMax %@ : ",tempMax);
        NSLog(@"tempMin %@ : ",tempMin);
        NSLog(@"description %@ : ",description);
        NSLog(@"deg %@ : ",deg);
        NSLog(@"speed %@ : ",speed);

       NSLog(@"dasdasddasdataioioio : %@",json);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"dasdasddasdata : %@",error);
    }


}].resume;

}
```

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks

Comment: `let count = list.count
    if count > 0`?! Just do `if !list.isEmpty`

Comment: And it doesn't even matter, if the list is empty, the `for` loop won't do anything

Comment: But I am initially adding it to an array. The line before it.                                               **rr.add(city)**

Comment: No , rr is a local variable let rr = NSMutableArray() for every call it's empty

Comment: I have added the entire code, can you please help me figure it out.

Comment: And I couldnt get an append function, I am getting only the add function.

Comment: add is ok also , copy paste my 2 function and run to see then give me feedback now

Comment: don't forget to initalize listData = NSMutableArray() in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yeah I get it. Firstly I am trying to make the code work and then assign them to proper classes..Thats why its written in one file

Comment: @Alexander Why do you think that loop is working properly but the api call is not happening with the entire loop. Do you have any alternate solutions instead of for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the collectionView after each request completes by calling `reloadData` inside your networking callback, though that's a bit inefficient unless you really need to reload after each item.  If you want to wait until all data is loaded before reloading your `collectionView` you may consider using a `DispatchGroup`.  That could work like this:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func updateValues()  {
let list = getSearchHistory()
let count = list.count
    if count > 0 {
        for item in list {
            dispatchGroup.enter() //Indicate that a new process is beginning in the dispatch group
            getData(name: item as! String)
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) { //When all processes in the group finish this code will execute
            self.cv.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func getData(name: String)  {
    let modified = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(modified)&APPID=------------------"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: HTTPMethod.get).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
        let city = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
        self.listData.append(rr)
        dispatchGroup.leave() //Indicate that a process is ending in the dispatch group
    })
}
```

Comment: that's not a good ux as the user should wait for all the responses to complete especially in this case array size may be 50 or more as he uses **openweathermap** apis

Comment: @Sh_Khan The user can decide how they want to do it.  Some people prefer a loading screen rather than a weird cascading collection view load where new items keep popping up at random times.

Comment: most users like that cascading load as it makes them feel that app is responsive and it's a matter of internet loading instead of being waiting all responses that makes them quite the app thinking it's slow or unresponsive anyway good day !!

Comment: @Sh_Khan I appreciate the discussion!  I just thought it's always good to have multiple options.

Comment: @xxxxx What is not working?  Did you make sure to add the `.leave()` call in your AlamoFire callback?  Also - this will wait until all calls finish before reloading the collectionView.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that, I am just adding a link where you can see whats happening. Give me a minute

Comment: It's probably because you're replacing your array instead of adding to it with each call.  I'll update my answer to fix.